# Convert to Laravel Query

Tags: laravel

I have query for query data. That is document.

```
"SELECT        
     zk_z_hako * CASE WHEN  zk_n_iri>  0 THEN zk_n_iri ELSE 1 END
   + zk_z_bara 
   - ifnull(
                sum(
                        ns_hako 
          * CASE WHEN  zk_n_iri>  0 THEN zk_n_iri ELSE 1 END                
                  * CASE WHEN  ns_tr_kbn in (0,6) OR ( ns_tr_kbn = 1 AND ns_ns_kbn = 7) THEN 1
                         WHEN  ns_tr_kbn in (1,7)                                       THEN (-1)
                 ELSE  0
                        END
                  +  ns_bara
                  *  CASE WHEN  ns_tr_kbn in (0,6) OR ( ns_tr_kbn = 1 AND ns_ns_kbn = 7) THEN 1
                          WHEN  ns_tr_kbn in (1,7)                                       THEN (-1)
                  ELSE  0
                        END )
                ,0 )  AS TOTAL_BARA
FROM    t_table1
LEFT JOIN t_table2
                ON        ns_kno = zk_kno
AND         ns_show_flg = 0
AND     ns_ymd > 'Date param'      
WHERE        zk_kno = Value param;
```

So I am not a master of Laravel. Now I need to convert this query for work with laravel. Anyone can help me?

And i have to try this query.

```
$squery = 'zk_z_hako * CASE WHEN  zk_n_iri>  0 THEN zk_n_iri ELSE 1 END
   + zk_z_bara 
    ifnull(
                sum(
                        ns_hako 
          * CASE WHEN  zk_n_iri>  0 THEN zk_n_iri ELSE 1 END                
                  * CASE WHEN  ns_tr_kbn in (0,6) OR ( ns_tr_kbn = 1 AND ns_ns_kbn = 7) THEN 1
                         WHEN  ns_tr_kbn in (1,7)                                       THEN (-1)
                 ELSE  0
                        END
                  +  ns_bara
                  *  CASE WHEN  ns_tr_kbn in (0,6) OR ( ns_tr_kbn = 1 AND ns_ns_kbn = 7) THEN 1
                          WHEN  ns_tr_kbn in (1,7)                                       THEN (-1)
                  ELSE  0
                        END )
                ,0 )  AS TOTAL_BARA ';
        $param1= '20160310';
        $param2= '1972640100';
        $results = DB::table('table1')
          ->select($squery)
        ->leftJoin('table2', function($join) use ($param1)
            {
                $join->on('table1.ns_kno', '=', 'table2.zk_kno');
                $join->on('table1.ns_show_flg', '=', DB::raw(0));
                $join->on('ns_ymd','>',DB::raw("'".$param1."'"));
            })
        ->where('zk_kno', DB::raw($param2))
        ->toSql()
```

But it's return sql

```
"select `zk_z_hako` as `CASE` from `t_zaikmst` left join `t_nsyutrn` on `t_nsyutrn`.`ns_kno` = `t_zaikmst`.`zk_kno` and `t_nsyutrn`.`ns_show_flg` = 0 and `ns_ymd` > '20160310' where `zk_kno` = 1972640100"
```

i don't sure it true.

Comment: Yes, i have problem with select command. So how to convert select. it's seem complex.

Comment: First of all, you can't add `case, when` in `->select()`, you've to use DB::raw() for that. In select function, you just have to add attributes.

Comment: i see. i will check more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make custom select than you need to use raw queries as `select` parameter like this:

```
->select(\DB::raw($squery))
```